# In ASP.NET encoded quotes prevent request from reaching the route

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, routes, urlencode

In ASP.NET encoded quotes prevent request from reaching the route. How could I fix this?

In my case the issue is the following.

I am making the request:`https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/foo` and the request reached my controller: I am able to debug the controller and see that everything is fine. Also I am getting the response: `[{"code":"1code","title":"\"foo\" short (1code)","id":"1code"}]`.

Then I try the following request:`https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/%22foo%22` and the request do not reach my controller at all.

Here is what my route looks like on the BE:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/businessAttributes/contractors/{searchString?}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<BusinessAttributeSimpleListEntryDto>> GetContractors(string searchString = null)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I missing here?

The only way to fix the issue which I was able to find is to change the controller to

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/businessAttributes/contractors")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<BusinessAttributeSimpleListEntryDto>> GetContractors([FromUri]string searchString = null)
```

And the request to `https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors?searchString=%22foo%22`.

Are there any better ways to fix the issue?

**UPDATE**

After the suggestions in the comment section I tried to append the `/` to the end of the request, to have the following request: `https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/%22foo%22/`. That did not help.

Comment: And also the image that you have posted with url https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/%22foo%22 has a status of 200, if it wasnt found it should have returned a 404. Can you check if you are handling the data correctly or put a break point to check if it gets hit

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat, `the request do not reach my controller at all.`. I tried putting the breakpoint and it worked for the `https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/foo`, but not for the `https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/%22foo%22`.

Comment: I tried creating a similar endpoint and made a similar call from postman I was able to hit the endpoint `https://localhost:44364/api/businessAttributes/contractors/%22foo%22`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to url encode " in to %22

You can simply make use of [EscapeUriString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
string encodedUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
```

After it hits the endpoint your searchString would be `"\"foo\""` or `"foo"` not `foo`. Make sure you handle that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But, please, read the question more carefully. The solution you suggest was attempted.

Comment: Also, it seems that you do not understand the issue here. I have an issue on client side, while you are doing something on the server side or does the js have the `string` keyword for a type?

Comment: can you post the js code from which you are making this call

Comment: I am sorry. I do not have access to the js.